# Why I get number instead of names after processing my data in R?

Tags: r

I have very big data set. I have to do some preprocessing in my data set. I do the following steps in my data set, but I get number for the second column insteas of names. but when I run the code on simple data set, it work well. does anybody knows what is the problem ? and how can I remove `""` from output?

some parts of my data set :

```
> tars.hsa.miRBase[1:4,]
                                                                                                                     miRBaseid
1 hsa-let-7a/hsa-let-7b/hsa-let-7c/hsa-let-7d/hsa-let-7e/hsa-let-7f/hsa-miR-98/hsa-let-7g/hsa-let-7i/hsa-miR-4458/hsa-miR-4500
2 hsa-let-7a/hsa-let-7b/hsa-let-7c/hsa-let-7d/hsa-let-7e/hsa-let-7f/hsa-miR-98/hsa-let-7g/hsa-let-7i/hsa-miR-4458/hsa-miR-4500
3 hsa-let-7a/hsa-let-7b/hsa-let-7c/hsa-let-7d/hsa-let-7e/hsa-let-7f/hsa-miR-98/hsa-let-7g/hsa-let-7i/hsa-miR-4458/hsa-miR-4500
4 hsa-let-7a/hsa-let-7b/hsa-let-7c/hsa-let-7d/hsa-let-7e/hsa-let-7f/hsa-miR-98/hsa-let-7g/hsa-let-7i/hsa-miR-4458/hsa-miR-4500
  Gene.Symbol Transcript.ID
1      SCARA3     NM_016240
2      IGLON5  NM_001101372
3        IRF5  NM_001098630
4        ELL2     NM_012081
```

My code :

```
ind.mirs <- strsplit(tars.hsa.miRBase[, "miRBaseid"], split="/")

lclus    <- (sapply(ind.mirs, length))
new.tars <- matrix(NA,sum(lclus),2)
new.tars[,1] <- do.call(c,ind.mirs)
new.tars[,2] <- rep(tars.hsa.miRBase$Gene.Symbol, time=lclus )
```

Some part of output :

```
     [,1]         [,2]   
[1,] "hsa-let-7a" "13883"
[2,] "hsa-let-7b" "13883"
[3,] "hsa-let-7c" "13883"
[4,] "hsa-let-7d" "13883"
```

What I expected :

```
     miRBaseid         Gene.Symbol   
    [1,] hsa-let-7a  SCARA3
    [2,] hsa-let-7b  SCARA3
    [3,] hsa-let-7c  SCARA3
    [4,] hsa-let-7d  SCARA3
.
.
.
.
```

How is it work on simple data :

```
tars.hsa <- data.frame(miR.Family=c("a","b/b","c/c","d/d/d"), Gene.Symbol=paste0("A",1:4,"BG"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ind.mirs <- strsplit(tars.hsa[, "miR.Family"], split="/")

lclus    <- sapply(ind.mirs, length)
new.tars <- matrix(NA,sum(lclus),2)
new.tars[,1] <- do.call(c,ind.mirs)
new.tars[,2] <- rep(tars.hsa$Gene.Symbol, time=lclus )
```

OutPut:

```
     [,1] [,2]  
[1,] "a"  "A1BG"
[2,] "b"  "A2BG"
[3,] "b"  "A2BG"
[4,] "c"  "A3BG"
[5,] "c"  "A3BG"
[6,] "d"  "A4BG"
[7,] "d"  "A4BG"
[8,] "d"  "A4BG"
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that you are getting the numeric index of the factor level that corresponds to "SCARA3" in your dataset (in this case, 13883). This is being caused by two main issues: first, the matrix has to be all one data type in R, and second, the code is treating the text as factor levels.

If you use a data frame instead of a matrix, each column can have its own data type, so you can have a column that is text and another that is numeric. Alternatively, you might try the `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` option to change how R processes strings.

Getting rid of the `""` signs that you are worried about would also be accomplished by handling the data as a data frame and not a matrix; they are appearing because you are creating a character matrix. They aren't being stored in the data itself, but are there for display (IIRC).

EDITED TO ADD:

Okay, a longer explanation. In R, when you have a vector of character data, by default R assumes that those represent categorical variables. For instance, if you have a variable `race` in your dataset with different character strings ("White", "Black", "Asian", and so on), it automatically creates a factor. A factor in R is a special kind of character variable that has different rules in modeling and such.

If I create example data from your question, like this:

```
tars.hsa.miRBase <- data.frame(miRBaseid=c("hsa-let-7a/hsa-let-7b/hsa-let-7c/hsa-let-7d/hsa-let-7e/hsa-let-7f/hsa-miR-98/hsa-let-7g/hsa-let-7i/hsa-miR-4458/hsa-miR-4500",
                                           "hsa-let-7a/hsa-let-7b/hsa-let-7c/hsa-let-7d/hsa-let-7e/hsa-let-7f/hsa-miR-98/hsa-let-7g/hsa-let-7i/hsa-miR-4458/hsa-miR-4500",
                                           "hsa-let-7a/hsa-let-7b/hsa-let-7c/hsa-let-7d/hsa-let-7e/hsa-let-7f/hsa-miR-98/hsa-let-7g/hsa-let-7i/hsa-miR-4458/hsa-miR-4500",
                                           "hsa-let-7a/hsa-let-7b/hsa-let-7c/hsa-let-7d/hsa-let-7e/hsa-let-7f/hsa-miR-98/hsa-let-7g/hsa-let-7i/hsa-miR-4458/hsa-miR-4500"),
                               Gene.Symbol=c("SCARA3","IGLON5","IRF5","ELL2"),
                               Transcript.ID=c("NM_016240","NM_001101372","NM_001098630","NM_012081"))
```

The resulting data is made into factors:

```
[1] SCARA3 IGLON5 IRF5   ELL2  
Levels: ELL2 IGLON5 IRF5 SCARA3
```

You can tell that the data is a factor because of the "Levels:" statement below the results. To get around this, you can tell R not to treat strings as factors `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` and you can pass data through `as.character` to ignore the factor levels.

```
> as.character(tars.hsa.miRBase$Gene.Symbol)
[1] "SCARA3" "IGLON5" "IRF5"   "ELL2"
```

See how it changes the output?

```
ind.mirs <- strsplit(as.character(tars.hsa.miRBase[,"miRBaseid"]), split="/")
lclus <- sapply(ind.mirs, length)
new.tars <- matrix(NA,sum(lclus),2)
new.tars[,1] <- do.call(c,ind.mirs)
new.tars[,2] <- rep(as.character(tars.hsa.miRBase$Gene.Symbol), time=lclus)

> new.tars
      [,1]           [,2]    
 [1,] "hsa-let-7a"   "SCARA3"
 [2,] "hsa-let-7b"   "SCARA3"
 [3,] "hsa-let-7c"   "SCARA3"
 [4,] "hsa-let-7d"   "SCARA3"
 [5,] "hsa-let-7e"   "SCARA3"
```

Comment: I get error and warning when I use data frame. could you please specify your solution more ?

Comment: I will see if I can put together an example.

Comment: Does this make sense?

Comment: it's great. thanks man. how can I remove the  " " sign  from the reslut?

Comment: The `""` sign is part of the display as they are character variables. It's not stored in the variable as far as I know.